# Retrieving data of Nearby devices containing same application

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cllocationmanager

I'm developing a chat application, and a requirement is to get the device details for users within some distance (i.e., devices within 100 miles who are using same application).  I want to get the details and they should be shown in a `UITableView`.

Answer (score 1):

There are far too many pieces involved in this for a single answer to include all the code, however I can give you a high-level overview:

1. You'll need to send the device's current location (found with `CLLocationManager`) and an identifier to a remote server on `applicationDidBecomeActive:` and whenever you determine that the user has moved a significant distance.
2. Your remote server stores these coordinates, the identifier, and a timestamp into a database table and periodically prunes old entries.
3. When you load the "Nearby Users" screen your devices makes a request with its own location to the server, which returns the list of users within 100 miles.  The [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) is the proper way to calculate distances between GPS coordinates.  Once you have the results, you can show them in a `UITableView`.
4. When the user selects a nearby user, you can use the identifier it sent in step 1 to start brokering a connection between them.  This part is highly dependent on your specific chat system.